# Undefined is not an object with MapView.Animated (refs are not working)

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

```
<MapView.Animated
  ref={(mapView) => { map = mapView; }}
  style={[styles.map, styleMap]}
  initialRegion={{
     latitude: LATITUDE,
     longitude: LONGITUDE,
     latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
     longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
     }}>
</MapView.Animated>

<TouchableOpacity
   onPress={()=>this.map.animateCamera({
   center: {
     latitude: this.state.userLocation.latitude,
     longitude: this.state.userLocation.longitude,
            },
   pitch: 45>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

It rights me [image]

Ofc there is exterior view and stuff... help please:)
Also I've tried to rename ref to map, making it 'var something:MapView,
it didnt work too

TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE
TRAIN ASKED ME TO DROP SOME CODE

```
class ChooseLocationScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.map = React.createRef()
        this.state = {
            coordinate: new AnimatedRegion({
                latitude: LATITUDE,
                longitude: LONGITUDE,
                latitudeDelta: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0,
            }),
            userLocation: new AnimatedRegion({
                latitude: LATITUDE,
                longitude: LONGITUDE,
                latitudeDelta: 0,
                longitudeDelta: 0,
            }),
            markerAnimation: new Animated.Value(0),
            animation: new Animated.Value(0),
            animationSides: new Animated.Value(1),
            animationSides2: new Animated.Value(1),
            mapActive: true,
            isSearchScreen: false,
            searchValue: '',
            myGeo: false,
        };

    }





    render() {

        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                <Animated.View style={[styles.mapContainer, animatedStyles]}>
                    <MapView.Animated
                        ref={(mapView) => { map = mapView; }}
                        showsUserLocation={true}
                        onRegionChange={() => this.onPanDrag()}
                        showsMyLocationButton={true}
                        onRegionChangeComplete={() => this.onRegionChangeComplete()}
                        style={[styles.map, styleMap]}
                        initialRegion={{
                            latitude: LATITUDE,
                            longitude: LONGITUDE,
                            latitudeDelta: LATITUDE_DELTA,
                            longitudeDelta: LONGITUDE_DELTA,
                        }}
                        zoomEnabled={this.state.mapActive}
                        scrollEnabled={this.state.mapActive}
                        onPress={this.mapPressBackHandler}>
                    </MapView.Animated>

                </Animated.View>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    onPress={() => this.map.animateCamera({
                        center: {
                            latitude: this.state.userLocation.latitude,
                            longitude: this.state.userLocation.longitude,
                        },
                        pitch: 4
                    })}
                    style={{ position: 'absolute', top: height * 3.5 / 4, right: width / 18, zIndex: 2, alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    {TextNewsIcon()}
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `ref={(mapView) => { map = mapView; }}` where are you instantiating map? Have you bound it in the constructor?

Comment: Please show us all your code.

Comment: @Train nope I haven't, how to do that?

Comment: gave you the code... help please :D

Comment: Sure thing, as soon as I get some time I will take a loot at it.

Comment: Just a quick comment, have you tried changing `ref={(mapView) => { map = mapView; }}` to `ref={(mapView) => { this.map = mapView; }}`

Comment: have just tried.. didn't work

Comment: it seems like ref doesn't work with ANIMATED MapView.\

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943986/changing-animatecamera-pitch-and-zoom-properties-dynamically-doesnt-work/71156487#71156487

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing in `this`.

You can use this code

```js
<MapView.Animated
  ref={(mapView) => { this.map = mapView; }}
  ....
<TouchableOpacity
onPress={()=>this.map.animateCamera({
....
```

And `animateCamera` has no location parameters.

**animateCamera**

```
camera: Camera, { duration: Number }
```